# How to tap and hold (Long press) using appium for Android?

Tags: appium

Is there any code to tap and hold on Appium? i use python , is there any command to support it ?

For double click i used click on element twice, for tap and hold i am not getting any solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Need to pass driver

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
action.longPress(webElement).release().perform();
```

Comment: action.longPress(webElement) does not work, it requires longPressOptions
Here is the error if i pass MobileElement or WebElement :
Cannot resolve method 'longPress(io.appium.java_client.MobileElement)'

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use TouchAction class to longPress any element. Try this:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction();
action.longPress(webElement).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 8):

In latest Java client versions below will work.

```
AndroidTouchAction touch = new AndroidTouchAction (driver);
touch.longPress(LongPressOptions.longPressOptions()
                .withElement (ElementOption.element (element)))
              .perform ();

System.out.println("LongPressed Tapped");
```

Comment: What is the default longpress time?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the update for `Java Client: 5.0.4`

```
WebElement recBtn = driver.findElement(MobileBy.id("img_button"));
new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver).press(recBtn).waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(10000)).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this. The duration is calculated in milliseconds, so it need to multiply by 1000 as 1 second.

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
action.longPress(webElement,duration*1000).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
action.longPress(element);
action.perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 TouchAction action=new TouchAction(driver);
 action.longPress(ele, 2);
 action.perform();
 2ndway
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("mobile: longClickGesture",              
 ImmutableMap.of("elementId",((RemoteWebElement)ele).getId(),
                "duration",2000));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Following worked:

```
    MobileElement longpress = driver.findElement({element find strategy})
    LongPressOptions longPressOptions = new LongPressOptions();
    longPressOptions.withDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).withElement(ElementOption.element(longpress));
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
    action.longPress(longPressOptions).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have identified the pageElement you want to longPress on.

```
//pageElement

editPreferenceButton = driver.whatever 

//code for waiting for display of element

waitForDisplayed(editPreferenceButton, 10)
        
//this line is not required, keeping it here for easy readability

MobileElement longpress = editPreferenceButton;

//use the below code, it will do the trick, credits to wherever i found this

LongPressOptions longPressOptions = new LongPressOptions();               longPressOptions.withDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).withElement(ElementOption.element(longpress));
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
action.longPress(longPressOptions).release().perform();}
```