# How do I longpress on iOS?

Tags: python, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to long press an element on my screen. I do not have it working for iOS.

On android the following works:

```
user_action = TouchAction(self.driver)
elementname = self.driver.find_element_by_id(element)
user_action.long_press(elementname).perform()
```

While on iOS this simply taps the element. I also tried putting x, y and a long duration `(x=200, y=550, duration=100000)`, but it still acts as a simple, immediate tap.

I am using **Appium 1.17.1** on macOS. I have tried with real devices and emulators.

Is there a special way of doing a long press on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding in **.release()** like this:

```
user_action = TouchAction(self.driver)
elementname = self.driver.find_element_by_id(element)
user_action.long_press(elementname).release().perform()
```

as found here: [How to tap and hold (Long press) using appium for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298096/how-to-tap-and-hold-long-press-using-appium-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

1. Which automation engine (driver) are you using ?

```
XCUITest
UIAutomation
```

2. Have you tried running the same code with other elements? If not, can you try it with few other elements.

Comment: I am using XCUITest and I tried the same with some other long-pressable elements just now. They also seemed to have a click rather than a longpress, but I cannot confirm 100% due to the similarity between longpress and click on text fields.

I managed to get a longpress performed by adding in .release() before .perform()!

Answer (score 0):

**Working solution** with:
Python 3.x, Appium 1.22.3-4 [Released on 15th May, 2022], Mac M1

- *Long press* on iOS can be achieve using snippet

> **TouchAction(driver).long_press(element).release().perform()**